# Angular Material Components have weird styles

Tags: angular, angular-material

I don't know why my material components are so weird as if they were badly implemented in my app.

Here is the slide toggle

[image: Material Slide Toggle]

```
  <div
    fxFlex
    fxLayoutAlign="end center"
    fxLayout="row"
    fxLayoutGap="10px"
    class="right-header margin-right-x2"
  >
     ...
    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="end center" class="theme-container">
      <mat-slide-toggle (click)="toggleTheme()" [checked]="isDarkTheme">
        <mat-icon class="header-icon">highlight</mat-icon>
      </mat-slide-toggle>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And tooltip, displayed everytime at the bottom of my app

[image: Tooltip]

```
  <div
    fxLayoutAlign="start center"
    fxLayout="column"
    fxLayoutGap="15px"
    matTooltip="This is a tooltip"
    class="contacts-container"
  >
    <a>
    </a>
  </div>
```

If you could help me with this, I would be grateful! Thanks.

Comment: You should try uninstalling and installing material again, some styles are missing or try checking angular.json for proper imports else just uninstall it and do `ng add @angular/material`

Comment: please add the template of the components

Comment: Need your code to figure out what happen here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thanks to @Navitas28, I've figured it out when reinstalling that I forgot to import mat-core() in my styles.scss !
Stupid mistake from me..

Thanks for your answers, Have a good day!